# Why is my PHP function sometimes firing false when the JSON payload is correct?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

```
$check = json_decode(file_get_contents('JSONPAYLOADWEBSITE') , true);   
        $debug = json_encode($check);
        $site_url = get_site_url(); (Wordpress gets Site Address)
        if (!empty($check)) {
            $ax = 'Not Ready'; 

            foreach ($check as $c) {
                if ($c['title']['rendered'] == $site_url) {
                    $ax = 'Ready'; 
                }
            }


            if ($ax == 'Not Ready') {
//  every few hours it will say Not Ready, even though the $debug and $site_url have data that should make it Ready
            }
        }
```

Is there something explicitly wrong with my code to where it would create false positives, the site URL and the debug variable send me data that would be considered valid and if I rerun my function with the data sent to me when it returns Not Ready it runs correctly as Ready, so I'm not sure if this is a memory leak or maybe something is wrong with my checks?

My JSON Payload looks like this:

```
[
{
title: {
rendered: "https://www.site1.com"
}
},
{
title: {
rendered: "https://site2.com"
}
},
{
title: {
rendered: "https://site3.com"
}
},
{
title: {
rendered: "https://site4.com"
}
}
]
```

Comment: The payload is correct or else it would not be assigning anything to `$ax` in the first place. Apparently the $site_url is not in any of the values. I would suggest finding a way to log the json when `$ax` is `Not Ready` so you can look through it to see what the current values are. I would suggest also logging `$site_url` just to verify.

Comment: The issue is that I have it returning $site_url and the JSON which all seems to be correct and fine, but it still returns Not Ready, this doesn't happen every time, but once every few hours so very hard to find out why. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: Without knowing the exact data at that time, no. That's why I suggest writing the json and site_url to a file inside of your `'Not Ready'` block, so you can see exactly what the values are at that time.

Comment: Yes I know what you're saying, I have done that but didn't include it in my question. It returns valid data so no server issue or anything, it just seems to not trigger Ready in my PHP code

Comment: could you show us (a sample of) the _valid_ logged data which still results in `$ax == 'Not Ready'`

Comment: The response is encoded, this is what was in $debug = [{"title":{"rendered":"https:\/\/goldentipsters.com"}},{"title":{"rendered":"https:\/\/bot-demo-co-uk.pagehost.co.uk"}},{"title":{"rendered":"https:\/\/no1tipsterpremium.com"}}]

and the $siteurl variable had "https-://-www.goldentipsters.com" without the dashes and quotes this is all valid data logged when Not Ready

Comment: Can you post the url inside of ticks so that it doesn't get formatted by the browser?

Comment: `https://goldentipsters.com`

Comment: `https://goldentipsters.com` in your json is not the same as `https://www.goldentipsters.com` as your site_url. You may need to parse out the url for both to check for just the domain.

Comment: There is no www. in the website URL, it's like this `https://goldentipsters.com` that's the value of $siteurl

Comment: Ah, sorry, the first time you tried to post it and fixed it with the dashes, it had www on it.

Comment: When I rerun the script and copy and paste the debug payload and the siteurl data, it runs as Ready, so it's very difficult to debug this, perhaps there is a better way of checking a license, as this function loads on every reload